# Transparent method "DotNetOpenAuth. Messaging. MessagingUtilities. AsActionResult (DotNetOpenAuth. Messaging. OutgoingWebResponse)" failure

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Auth2 using certificates for token
    var configuration = new AuthorizationServerConfiguration
    {
        EncryptionCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("~/Certs/3drp.cer")),
        SigningCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Server.MapPath("~/Certs/3drp.pfx"), "123")
    };

    var authorizationServer = new AuthorizationServer(new AuthorizationServerHost(configuration));
    var response = authorizationServer.HandleTokenRequest(Request);
    return response.AsActionResult();
}
```

error: [image: error]

> Transparent method "DotNetOpenAuth. Messaging. MessagingUtilities. AsActionResult (DotNetOpenAuth. Messaging. OutgoingWebResponse)"
>   Try to access security key type "System. Web. Mvc. ActionResult" failure.

[image]

Comment: Please include a few more details about your question.

Comment: The problems when using oauth2 authorization, access token, use mode is the certificate